# Is TTFB(Time To First Byte) score solely depends on the server/web hosting?

Tags: performance, load, pagespeed

I have two simple custom php sites located in the same VPS server. Im using webpagetest.org to see the score. SITE1 scores A=200ms, SITE2 scores F=1000ms. I dont understand, i thought if I use the same server the TTFB scores should be around the same??

I also use Chrome's inspect, around the same result SITE1 27ms, SITE2 780ms. But both sites scores above 97/100 using googles pagespeed test. Could it be the codes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Found the problem, it was one of the scripts. Now TTFB 32ms.